# Does there exist the possibility of a search for closed questions, collectively comprising all users?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Since I am here, I always liked those questions (mine and those of other users) most, which have eventually been closed. They always were the most interesting ones.

While it is possible to look up my own closed questions, I do not see how I could start a search for closed questions, *collectively encompassing* all users.

Does such a collective search possibility exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can search for "[closed:yes](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes)".

There are more advanced search options, you can read more about them by clicking "Advanced Search Tips" on the right top of the search page (only on desktop view) or [in the help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/searching).